# Accessing localhost served from a Debian VM on Windows

Tags: localhost, virtual-machine

I am using Windows 10 and I have a VM running Debian. I want to use Jekyll in Debian to build and serve pages onto localhost, and then view the pages from a browser in my native windows environment.

**How do I access localhost served from within the VM from the native browser in windows?**

I'm sorry if this question is repetitive, the other similar questions seemed to be asking the other way around and I couldn't get it working.

Comment: what virtual machine software are you using?

Comment: I'm using Oracle VM Virtual Box 5.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the network configuration to use [bridged](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) mode.

The guest OS will then aquire an IP from your local network if it is configure to use DHCP. Otherwise, set a fixed IP in the range of your network.

Then you can access the server running in the guest OS from the host using that IP address.

But you could also use [port forwarding](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) on a conventional NAT configuration. The server would be available on the host IP under the forwarded port.

Comment: Thank you. And how do I find out what that IP address is?

Comment: Use the `ifconfig` command in the guest to list the interfaces, IP should be in the output.

Comment: Hmm... I got my ip but still can't reach it from that address... :( I used bridged mode and restarted the VM

Comment: Thank you! Got it working now

Answer (score 1):

After you set ip for your VM that are in bridge mode, you must first test if the port that use in VM are open with this command:

```
telnet ip_address port_number
```

If result is like this

> Trying ip_address...
>
> connected to ip_address.
>
> Escape character is '^]'.

the port is open and the problem is aside from your service that run on this port in VM. If the result are failed, the problem is aside firewall. you can open that port via *iptables* command:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport port_number -j ACCEPT
```

if your port are udp, replace all tcp with udp in above command.

Comment: Thank you. How do I set the ip and port for my VM ?  I am sorry I am new to all of this.